# Implementing PayPal subscription with no trial period

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, subscription, paypal-subscriptions, trial

I am using this code for subscription for PayPal payment

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions" />
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="a@a.com" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="this is buy" />
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe!" />
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP"/>
        <input type='hidden' name='custom' value='777sdfsdf' />
        <input type='hidden' name='invoice' value='103' />

        <input type="hidden" name="a1" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="p1" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="t1" value="D" />
        <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="10.00" />
        <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D" />
        <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="srt" value="52" />
        <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1" />           

    </form>
```

This work fine with one day of trial period  but my requirement is that i don't want to give free trial to user , so when i use this

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions" />
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="a@a.com" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="this is buy" />
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe!" />
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP"/>
        <input type='hidden' name='custom' value='777sdfsdf' />
        <input type='hidden' name='invoice' value='103' />

        <input type="hidden" name="a1" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="p1" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="t1" value="D" />
        <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="10.00" />
        <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D" />
        <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="srt" value="52" />
        <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1" />           
    </form>
```

i get following error when user click and go to PayPal

```
Invalid first trial period. You must specify valid values for the A1, P1 and T1 parameters for a subscription.
```

**MY Finding**
i search and find that there should be at least one trial period , but i didn't able to find how to implement no trial period using above method 
i don't want to change to use any other way of payment in PayPal

**FYI :** i am using sandbox for testing , so i hope same situation is in live PayPal environment

Answer (score 0):

Trial period is not required. However, all periods must be valid (ie cannot have zero length).

Drop the zero-length period and just list the periods you want. So what you were calling period 1 becomes period 0 (which would be the only period, in your example).

Comment: i dont understand "Drop the zero-length period and just list the periods you want."

Comment: a1, p1, and t1 are optional. Do not specify them but give them invalid values (length 0 days) - remove these variables from your button.